# Displaying Different Time-Zone in Single HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html

I want do display Dates from different time-zone (PDT, IST, JST and AEST) on single HTML page. I'm not very proficient in JavaScript learning currently. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at Luxon: https://moment.github.io/luxon/ AFAIK JavaScript Date objects are a bit clunky when it comes to timezones, so using a library that was made for it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to display current date, the javascript Date() will automatically get the date based on local timezone.

```
var date = new Date();
```

You can also refer to all the methods javascript date supports here -> [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp](http://Date%20Ref)

Best way to handle dates is by using moment library

[https://momentjs.com/timezone/](http://moment)